# How to organize Redux Action-Creators for use in Redux-React

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using `react-redux` & `redux-thunk` for my project.

I have to inject my `actions` to a component by using `connect`.

> `connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])`

My task is one level up. I don't want just to inject multiple actions in this form:

```
{
  doThis(),
  doThat()
}
```

But in this form:

```
{
  this: {
    doThis1(),
    doThis2()
  }
  that: {
    doThat()
  }
}
```

So basically **my problem is** that I want to **dispatch multiple action-creator files** because I want them organized as such.

I tried this version which obviously doesn't work because dispatch is not injected in each **Thunk Action Creator**:

```
import * as actions from './actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dataActions: {
      ...actions.dataActions
    }
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

### So my final question is:

Am I even supposed to use Redux this way? Can I organize my files this way, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If instead of having one property per action creator, you want to structure your bound action creators in a couple of properties that each contain a group of action creators, you can do something like this:

```
import { bindActionCreators, .. } from 'redux';
..
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dataActions: bindActionCreators(actions.dataActions, dispatch),
    otherActions: bindActionCreators(actions.otherActions, dispatch),
    ..        
  };
};
```

The first argument to `bindActionCreators` is an object containing action-creator functions (e.g. an imported module that exports only action creators). In your actual component, you should then be able to use `this.props.dataActions.someDataAction(..)`.

If the question is just about whether you can keep different action creators in different files, you might not even want to group the action creators and just do this:

```
return {
  ...bindActionCreators(actionCreatorsFromOneModule, dispatch),
  ...bindActionCreators(actionCreatorsFromAnotherModule, dispatch),
  ..        
};
```